# Resume CABasicAnimation using negative speed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, calayer

I resume my CABasicAnimation with the following code:

```
    CFTimeInterval pausedtime = layer.timeOffset;
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() toLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
```

which is pretty straightforward. At the very end of [this](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/) article the author states that with negative `speed` value animation reverses. I can't understand what `timeOffset` and `beginTime` should look like in this case?

**P.S.** I am aware that I can reverse animation by obtaining current values from presentation layer and setting toValue and fromValue. I want to figure out if it is possible with speed property.

Comment: Hey, were you able to achieve this at the end?

Comment: @oneshot unfortunately no success(

Answer (score 3):

You will have problems with resuming an animation backwards with `.timeOffset = 0`. `.timeOffset = 0` means that the animation is at its beginning. So, with reverse speed the animation will be finished immediately. Thus, if you, for example, have animation which is removed automatically on completion — it won't play anything: just will disappear.

CAAnimation has poor documentation indeed. And their example of resuming uses `.beginTime` property only. We can use `.timeOffset` property instead.

**1. Set your layer's begin time to the current time of its container:**

```
// set begin time to current time of superlayer to start immediately
let sTime = layer.superlayer?.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), to: nil) ?? 0
layer.beginTime = sTime
```

**2. Go to the moment of animation, where you want to resume, using `.timeOffset`:**

```
// set starting point of animation to the current "progress"
layer.timeOffset = progress
```

Where `progress` is the time position you want to resume from in terms of animation duration. i.e. if you have an animation duration of 0.6 — then `0 ≤ progress ≤ 0.6`.

**3. Launch animation in reverse direction:**

```
// set negative speed to have reverse animation
layer.speed = -1.0
```

Don't forget to remove animation on its completion, if needed.

This is the picture of how these settings are applied in fact:

[image: CALayer timing with reverse speed explained.]

Comment: What's the origin of this pic?

Comment: I've drawn it by myself :)

Comment: @DmytroBabych i've found your answer super helpful in understanding the basic dynamics running under the hood, thank you so much, i left you an upvote. Still when i try to reverse the animation using your suggested method it is super glitchy. Could you please take a look at my question and lend me a hand? I would be super grateful! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65683369/resume-cabasicanimation-backwards-by-setting-speed-equal-to-1

Comment: An Xcode playground I made to explain and explore Core Animation interactively.