# Resume CABasicAnimation backwards by setting .speed equal to -1

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cabasicanimation, caanimation

**EDIT**: i've refactored the question a bit and solved part of the issue, now the question comes down to why does the presentation layer glitches/flashes when the animation is resumed. At this point tho i'm accepting any answer that makes the animation resume both forwards and backwards at will with no issue. I'm not sure the approach i'm using is the right one, i'm still pretty new to Swift.

**Note**: Sample project at the bottom, for having a better understanding of the issue.

In my project i'm pausing a `CABasicAnimation` by setting the layer `.speed` property to `0`, then i'm changing the animation value interactively by setting the layer's `.timeOffset` property equal to a `UISlider` `.value` property whenever the user scrolls the slider. By code:

```
layer.speed = 0
```

Then when the user slides:

```
layer.timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(sender.value)
```

Now i want to resume the animation backwards or forwards at will whenever the user gesture on the slider ends, so from the starting point related to the current animation value. The only viable solution i've found which runs smoothly is the following, but it works only going forwards:

```
let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
layer.speed = 1.0
layer.timeOffset = 0.0
layer.beginTime = 0.0
let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
```

Then i can simply pause it again at the completion of the animation:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
    layer.timeOffset = 0
    layer.speed = 0
 }
```

From my understanding, `.speed` not only defines the actual speed of the animation combined with the `.duration` property, but also the direction of the animation: if i set a layer's speed equal to `-1` then the animation completes backwards. Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38497567/5683179) answer in regards to how `CAMediaTiming` works, i was trying to change the up above snippet's parameters to resume the animation going backwards with no luck. I thought this would work:

```
let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
layer.timeOffset = 0.0
layer.beginTime = 0.0
let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
layer.timeOffset = pausedTime*2
layer.speed = -1.0
```

but the layer is never animated like so. The issue seems to be related to the `convertTime` method.

Then i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338092/resume-cabasicanimation-using-negative-speed) question which is basically the same of mine, and the only answer has a decent solution. Refactoring a bit the code, i can just say:

```
   layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
   layer.speed = -1
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
       layer.timeOffset = 0
       layer.speed = 0
   }
```

However, when the animation is played backwards is very glitchy, in particular the presentation layer flashes both at the resume and on completion. I've tried various solutions with no luck, some speculations i've made:

- it may be an issue related to `CAMediaTimingFillMode`, as i can set it `.back` or `.forwards` but when it resumes the animation is neither in it's final nor in it's initial state and thus the initial frame is not rendered;
- it is caused by the fact that i'm not keeping the modal tree and  the presentation tree synchronized.

Both of these however doesn't explain while it flickers/flashes both on resume and on completion. Additionally, it seems to me that the animation may have a duration of 1 when resumed forwards, but only of 1-timeOffset when resumed backwards, not sure tho.

Really not sure what's the actual problem and how to fix this mess. All suggestions are more than welcomed.

For anyone interested, here's a sample project similar to mine, inspired by another question (animation is running forward, to run it backwards and catch the glitch just call `resumeLayerBackwards()`). I know the code should be refactored, but still for the purpose it's fine. Just copy, paste and run:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var perspectiveLayer: CALayer = {
    let perspectiveLayer = CALayer()
    perspectiveLayer.speed = 0.0
    return perspectiveLayer
}()

var mainView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}()

private let slider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(slide(sender:event:)) , for: .valueChanged)
    return slider
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(slider)
    animate()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    slider.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width/3,
                          y: view.bounds.size.height/10*8,
                          width: view.bounds.size.width/3,
                          height: view.bounds.size.height/10)
}

@objc private func slide(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
    if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
        
      switch touchEvent.phase {
      case .ended:
        resumeLayer(layer: perspectiveLayer)
      default:
        perspectiveLayer.timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(sender.value)
      }
        
    }
}

private func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
        layer.timeOffset = 1.0
        layer.speed = 0.0
    }
}

private func resumeLayerBackwards(layer: CALayer) {  
        layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        layer.speed = -1
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
            layer.timeOffset = 0
            layer.speed = 0
        }
}


private func animate() {
    var transform:CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
    var topSleeve:CALayer
    var middleSleeve:CALayer
    var bottomSleeve:CALayer
    var topShadow:CALayer
    var middleShadow:CALayer
    let width:CGFloat = 300
    let height:CGFloat = 150
    var firstJointLayer:CALayer
    var secondJointLayer:CALayer
    
    mainView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: width, height: height*3))
    mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    view.addSubview(mainView)
            
    perspectiveLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height*2)
    mainView.layer.addSublayer(perspectiveLayer)
    
    firstJointLayer = CATransformLayer()
    firstJointLayer.frame = mainView.bounds
    perspectiveLayer.addSublayer(firstJointLayer)
    
    topSleeve = CALayer()
    topSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    topSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    topSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    topSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 0)
    firstJointLayer.addSublayer(topSleeve)
    topSleeve.masksToBounds = true
    
    secondJointLayer = CATransformLayer()
    secondJointLayer.frame = mainView.bounds
    secondJointLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height*2)
    secondJointLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    secondJointLayer.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height)
    firstJointLayer.addSublayer(secondJointLayer)
    
    middleSleeve = CALayer()
    middleSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    middleSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    middleSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    middleSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 0)
    secondJointLayer.addSublayer(middleSleeve)
    middleSleeve.masksToBounds = true
    
    bottomSleeve = CALayer()
    bottomSleeve.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: width, height: height)
    bottomSleeve.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    bottomSleeve.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    bottomSleeve.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height)
    secondJointLayer.addSublayer(bottomSleeve)
    
    firstJointLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    firstJointLayer.position = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 0)
    
    topShadow = CALayer()
    topSleeve.addSublayer(topShadow)
    topShadow.frame = topSleeve.bounds
    topShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    topShadow.opacity = 0
    
    middleShadow = CALayer()
    middleSleeve.addSublayer(middleShadow)
    middleShadow.frame = middleSleeve.bounds
    middleShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    middleShadow.opacity = 0
    
    transform.m34 = -1/700
    perspectiveLayer.sublayerTransform = transform
    
    var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = -90*Double.pi/180
    firstJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 180*Double.pi/180
    secondJointLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = -160*Double.pi/180
    bottomSleeve.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.height")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = perspectiveLayer.bounds.size.height
    animation.toValue = 0
    perspectiveLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = perspectiveLayer.position.y
    animation.toValue = 0
    perspectiveLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 0.5
    topShadow.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    
    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 0.5
    middleShadow.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to remove the glitch for `resumeLayerBackwards(layer:)` in the sample project.
Two problems there in fact:

1. there is an empty screen after animation has *visually* finished
2. the empty screen is visible for `1 - .timeOffset` seconds

So, seems like the problem is that animation in fact plays not just for `.timeOffset` period, but for the whole `.duration` period. And the empty screen appears because there is no animation defined for `1 - .timeOffset` block.

Just to recall: `CALayer` also adopts `CAMediaTiming` protocol, as `CAAnimation` does (with all the properties defined: although some of them seem not be very clear how to be applied to a layer).

With `speed = -1` after `.timeOffset` seconds passed — the property `.timeOffset` becomes equal to zero. It means that animation has reached its beginning and therefore (with negative speed) it is finished. Though it is not that obvious — seems like it is removed because of the `.fillMode` property. To fix this I've added `perspectiveLayer.fillMode = .forwards` to `animate()` method.

To have animation completed exactly after `.timeOffset` seconds instead of the whole `.duration` — use `.repeatDuration` property. I've added `layer.repeatDuration = layer.timeOffset` to your `resumeLayerBackwards(layer:)` method.

The project works only with both lines added.

I can't say that the solution is really logical for me, although it works. Negative speed works a bit unpredictable as for me. In my project I used to reverse animation by swapping begin and end values in cloned animation object.

Comment: Yep, it works now. I feel like i don't really understand how CAMediaTiming works, but it works and i'm fine with it. Thanks so much, really really appreciated your help.

Comment: Btw, after testing a bit, it appears that while the solution is working at first, as i slides multiple times the animation starts to break itself. I found better luck with your suggestion about swapping values + changing the model layers on completion.